# How to capture error 503 in chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-post, http-status-code-503, onerror

I want to capture errors on POST requests inside of all tabs in Google Chrome.

I used the following block of code to observe the firing of onErrorOccurred in extensions:

```
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
    function(details) {
        console.log("xxxxx");
        console.log(details);
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]});
```

But unfortunately this code cannot observe the error code 503. For example I made the following page that returns error 503.

http://mjza.rf.gd/index.php

I also tested the following code related to WebNavegation class but it does not work also:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/webNavigation/basic.zip

It would be great if someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extensions: Background Script Catch Network and HTTP Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106097/chrome-extensions-background-script-catch-network-and-http-errors)

Comment: listen to `onHeadersReceived`