# What are the possible values for the error property in a webRequest.onErrorOccurred listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

My interest is handling sites only during heavy load times for autofills to work. For example, when a sale opens and the site is swarmed, it sometimes crashes. I need to catch the site errors, so I can reload the page from the background script.
As described in [Chrome Extensions: Background Script Catch Network and HTTP Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106097/chrome-extensions-background-script-catch-network-and-http-errors), we can get the page load errors.

Page load error can be due to network issues, site issues, DNS issues, and also due to site overload issues.

All I want is to reload the web page in case it has not loaded due to some error.

I've collected many error codes for both Chrome and Firefox:

- net::ERR_ABORTED
- net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
- net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
- net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
- NS_ERROR_NET_ON_CONNECTING_TO
- NS_ERROR_NET_ON_WAITING_FOR
- NS_ERROR_NET_ON_CONNECTING_TO

This is not the full list. I've seen these errors, so I've listed them. Instead of finding them using trial and error, I want to know the list of all error codes when a (HTML) page won't load.

Here is the sample source code how I'd like to use:

```
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function (details) 
{
    if ("type" in details && ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'].indexOf(details.type) == -1)
    {
        if (details.url.match(/.js$/))
        {
            console.log("Error in download of this file:", details.url);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (details.tabId == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    var check_all_errors = function(err)
    {
        var all_errors = [
             "net::ERR_ABORTED",
             "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE",
             "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT",
             "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED",
             "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET",
             "NS_ERROR_NET_ON_CONNECTING_TO",
             'NS_ERROR_NET_ON_WAITING_FOR',
             'NS_ERROR_NET_ON_CONNECTING_TO'
        ];

        for( var i=0;i<all_errors.length;++i)
        {
            if( all_errors[i] == err && !ff_validate_false())
            {                
                return true;
            }
        }

        console.log("786 returning false for err "+err);
        return false;
    }

    if (details.url == HOME_URL && check_all_errors(details.error)) //if any error encountered then go to home URL
    {
        setTimeout(function () {
            chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: HOME_URL});
        }, 1000);
    }
    //FOLLOWING PART IS NOW SHOWN HERE
```

Comment: Please explain why using the code in the answer to the question you linked did not work for you.

Comment: Based on the results of simple Google searches using text from your question, you appear to have not tried to find a list of codes yourself.  Many different Google searches will get you pages which list the various possible error codes, and their descriptions.  For instance: [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), which includes unofficial codes. Note: You currently are listing the description text of the error, not the status code.  It will probably be easier for you to detect the actual 4xx or 5xx status code, not the descriptive text.

Comment: @Makyen I need code names like: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE not the http codes

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need them instead of the codes? What code are you using that shows those errors? Note that these do not appear to be from Firefox, as none of the ones you list, that are specific enough to make a reasonable search term, appear to be in the Firefox source code. At least *some* of them match in the [Chrome source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/domain_reliability/util.cc?q=ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE&l=46&dr=C) (that link will have a list of a reasonable number of them).

Comment: @Makyen see you yourself don't know the Firefox error codes etc .. why you downvoted? I've asked this question to get a clear answer about the codes. I've already collected many.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that I am the one that downvoted. I downvoted because this is a bad question, not because of the subject, but because of *how you have asked it*. You have not provided even minimal code that shows, or even text that *explicitly explains*, what is generating these errors and *exactly* where, *in your code*, you are encountering this error text. Without that information, your question is *dramatically* less useful to future readers. It is also harder to answer, because it makes the question one that we have to **guess** at what you are wanting. (cont')

Comment: (cont')The lack of information also makes the question one that is more about pattern matching (finding a *possible* list of errors that *happen* to include those you have specified), rather than one that is deterministic (find a list of the error texts that can be returned by operation X). You have pointed to some code in another question & answers, but that code deals with two distinct different types of errors, and you have not explained which you are interested in, or that you are interested in both (which *might* make this question too broad).(cont')

Comment: (cont')You've stated you want to react to "some error" this could mean that you want to react to *all* errors, or that you want to react to some *unspecified subset* of errors. Making it clear what you are wanting from the question, and what you are wanting from your code, would significantly improve the question. My downvote was only about the quality of the question, *as a question on SO*. If you improve the question, I may change that vote, retracting the downvote, or even upvoting. I specifically try to  return to questions I've downvoted after they're edited to see if they have improved.

Comment: @Makyen thanks, I've posted the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It is strongly recommended that you do not do this

For the [`error` property](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-details-error) <sup><sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onErrorOccurred#details))</sup></sup> provided in the [`details` object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-onErrorOccurred-details) <sup><sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onErrorOccurred#details))</sup></sup> passed to a [`webRequest.onErrorOccurred`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onErrorOccurred) <sup><sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onErrorOccurred))</sup></sup> listener, it is strongly recommended that you **not** test the actual text contents of that property.

### Chrome

The [Chrome source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/api/web_request.json?q=onErrorOccurred&l=550&dr=C) says:

> **You must not parse and act based upon its content.**

In [this line of code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/api/web_request.json?rcl=e80226a3b58c969b6a6c8002ce65bb7e786b96c4&l=568):

```
"error": {"type": "string", "description": "The error description. This string is <em>not</em> guaranteed to remain backwards compatible between releases. You must not parse and act based upon its content."}
```

The [documentation says](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-details-error):

> The error description. This string is not guaranteed to remain backwards compatible between releases. **You must not parse and act based upon its content.**

### Firefox

The [Firefox source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/698de2db1b16a5ef3c6a39f0f72885e69aee4022/toolkit/components/extensions/schemas/web_request.json#619) states:

> **You must not parse and act based upon its content.**

In [this line of code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/698de2db1b16a5ef3c6a39f0f72885e69aee4022/toolkit/components/extensions/schemas/web_request.json#619):

```
"error": {"type": "string", "description": "The error description. This string is <em>not</em> guaranteed to remain backwards compatible between releases. You must not parse and act based upon its content."}
```

The [documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onErrorOccurred#details):

> The error description. This string is an internal error string, may vary from one browser to another, and **is not guaranteed to stay the same between releases**.

## Current possible `error` values

### Chrome

Chrome has their list of possible error values in [this file](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/domain_reliability/util.cc?rcl=e80226a3b58c969b6a6c8002ce65bb7e786b96c4&l=26) ([some associated code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/error_page/common/localized_error.cc?rcl=e80226a3b58c969b6a6c8002ce65bb7e786b96c4&l=88)). That code is:

```
{ net::ERR_ABORTED, "aborted" },
{ net::ERR_TIMED_OUT, "tcp.connection.timed_out" },
{ net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED, "tcp.connection.closed" },
{ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, "tcp.connection.reset" },
{ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, "tcp.connection.refused" },
{ net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED, "tcp.connection.aborted" },
{ net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED, "tcp.connection.failed" },
{ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, "dns" },
{ net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, "ssl.protocol.error" },
{ net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID, "tcp.connection.address_invalid" },
{ net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE, "tcp.connection.address_unreachable" },
{ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, "tcp.connection.timed_out" },
{ net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED, "dns" },
{ net::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN,
    "ssl.cert.pinned_key_not_in_cert_chain" },
{ net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, "ssl.cert.name_invalid" },
{ net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID, "ssl.cert.date_invalid" },
{ net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, "ssl.cert.authority_invalid" },
{ net::ERR_CERT_REVOKED, "ssl.cert.revoked" },
{ net::ERR_CERT_INVALID, "ssl.cert.invalid" },
{ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, "http.response.empty" },
{ net::ERR_SPDY_PING_FAILED, "spdy.ping_failed" },
{ net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR, "spdy.protocol" },
{ net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR, "quic.protocol" },
{ net::ERR_DNS_MALFORMED_RESPONSE, "dns.protocol" },
{ net::ERR_DNS_SERVER_FAILED, "dns.server" },
{ net::ERR_DNS_TIMED_OUT, "dns.timed_out" },
{ net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE, "ssl" },
{ net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH, "http.response.content_length_mismatch" },
{ net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING,
    "http.response.incomplete_chunked_encoding" },
{ net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH,
    "ssl.version_or_cipher_mismatch" },
{ net::ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT, "ssl.bad_client_auth_cert" },
{ net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING,
    "http.response.invalid_chunked_encoding" },
{ net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED, "http.response.headers.truncated" },
{ net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE,
    "http.request.range_not_satisfiable" },
{ net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE, "http.response.invalid" },
{ net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
    "http.response.headers.multiple_content_disposition" },
{ net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_LENGTH,
    "http.response.headers.multiple_content_length" },
{ net::ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT, "ssl.unrecognized_name_alert" }
```

That means the possible values for Chrome are:

```
net::ERR_ABORTED
net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED
net::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN
net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
net::ERR_CERT_REVOKED
net::ERR_CERT_INVALID
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
net::ERR_SPDY_PING_FAILED
net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR
net::ERR_DNS_MALFORMED_RESPONSE
net::ERR_DNS_SERVER_FAILED
net::ERR_DNS_TIMED_OUT
net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
net::ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT
net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING
net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED
net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE
net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_LENGTH
net::ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT
```

### Firefox

Firefox is a bit more complex. WebExtensions is an API layered on top of the APIs that Firefox uses (and exposes to other types of add-ons).  The Firefox code changes the error-text responses it gets from the underlying API by:

```
let prefix = /^(?:ACTIVITY_SUBTYPE_|STATUS_)/;
let map = new Map();
for (let iface of [nsIHttpActivityObserver, nsISocketTransport]) {
  for (let c of Object.keys(iface).filter(name => prefix.test(name))) {
    map.set(iface[c], c.replace(prefix, "NS_ERROR_NET_ON_"));
  }
}
```

The code for the possible `ACTIVITY_SUBTYPE_` properties is in the file [nsIHttpActivityObserver.idl](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/http/nsIHttpActivityObserver.idl#65) and the definitions for the possible `STATUS_` properties is in [nsISocketTransport.idl](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/nsISocketTransport.idl#163). Performing the appropriate RegEx substitution results in the following possible values:

```
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_RESOLVING
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_RESOLVED
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_CONNECTING_TO
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_CONNECTED_TO
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_SENDING_TO
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_WAITING_FOR
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_RECEIVING_FROM
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_REQUEST_HEADER
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_REQUEST_BODY_SENT
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_RESPONSE_START
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_RESPONSE_HEADER
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_RESPONSE_COMPLETE
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_TRANSACTION_CLOSE
```

Comment: Thanks I also need to know relevant codes which can indicate error in page loading successfully

Comment: @user5858, All of the listed reasons are `error` values you get from a `webRequest.onErrorOccurred` event. All of them indicate the page did not load correctly. Just the fact that you got that event indicates the page did not load correctly. As the question/answer you linked to in the question shows, you should also monitor `webRequest.onHeadersReceived` for the `statusLine` property which can also indicate an error (probably both with and without also getting a `webRequest.onErrorOccurred` event). I'm not sure what more you are asking for. Please describe what you want in more detail.

Comment: @Makyen this post is relevant to my problem but did not help. Can you answer my query [HERE] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861130/webextesnion-webrequest-onerroroccurred-how-to-get-more-specific-error-details) and suggest any solution or workaround. I will be really thankful to you.